# jQuery news rotator not breaking without JavaScript

Tags: jquery, rotator

I'm trying to build a simple news rotator in jQuery and I'm looking at examples on the internet.

I'm trying to achieve something like this http://www.webstylepress.com/jquery-smooth-news-rotator/ but I want it to NOT break when JavaScript is disabled, just show the first element. I know that this is a very frequently asked question, but all of the examples I have seen break somehow when JavaScript is disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you simply hide all elements except the first one by default (using CSS). You can adjust the styles later if JavaScript is enabled and start the slider afterwards.